# Non linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Could you please help me in solving the problem posted below.

A company uses a raw material to produce two types of
products. When processed, each unit of raw material yields
2 units of product 1 and 1 unit of product 2. If x1 units of
product 1 are produced, then each unit can be sold for
$\$49-x_1,$ if $x_2$ units of product 2 are produced, then each
unit can be sold for $\$30-2x_2.$ It costs $\$5$ to purchase and
process each unit of raw material.

a) Use LINGO
b) What is the most that the company would be willing
to pay for an extra unit of raw material?

This problem is from Non-Linear Programming chapter.
Thank you,
Abhishek Baer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about LINGO, but mathematically:

$$ \max (49-x_1) x_1 + (30-x_2) x_2 - 5r$$
$$ \text{s.t.} 2x_1 + x_2 \leq 3r $$

Then part two of your question is the dual variable associated with that constraint.